# No me funciona mi Onclick CON FUNCION .remove("a"); CORRECTAMENTE

Tags: javascript, html

La pagina es https://asistescolar.com/cae/web/127/index.php.
`<a id="hore" OnClick="Definida();">➤Leer</a>`
Lo que quiero cuando realice clic no solo me lleve a leer todo el texto sino que borre el elemento a ¿por que no funciona?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("hore").remove("a");
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Definida() {
    bp0_id(6030); myFunction();
}
</script>
```

Comment: este es el código JavaScript <script type="text/javascript">  
function myFunction() {    document.getElementById("hore").remove("a"); 

}
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
function Definida() {
bp0_id(6030);

myFunction();

}
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
function Definidab() {
bp0_id(5788);

myFunction();

}
</script>

Comment: Quitale el mouseout, que solo molesta la lectura y se vuelve loca la página

Comment: Cuando termines de editar esta pregunta avisanos, mientras tanto mejor ni nos la miramos pues te estas haciendo un lio con el editor... Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio. Usa la ayuda del editor para aprender a poner el código. No pongas el código en los comentarios. Gracias.

Comment: Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/519805/edit) para agregar el código HTML del bloque que quieres modificar.

Comment: Visto, tu problema es que repites `id="hore"` en distintos `<a>`.  Los `id` deben ser únicos. Te está borrando solo el primero que encuentra, y no el que estas seleccionando. Usa una clase comun y un addEventListener, o usa `this` como parámetro de la función para que borre el elemento seleccionado y no el primero que encuentre.

Comment: GRACIA POR TU COMENTARIO masterguru
COLOQUE EL CÓDIGO HTML PARA QUE ENTIENDA MEJOR LA PREGUNTA PUDIERA ACLARAME MAS... CREO QUE EL PROBLEMA ES QUE ME LLEVA A UNA NUEVA PAGINA Y SE COLOCA DE NUEVO EL ENLACE ¿ ?

Comment: El método `remove()` va a eliminar el elemento solo en la página actual, pero no en la página nueva y, me pregunto... ¿Porqué aparece en esa página? Es decir, si ya estás viendo la información completa, no hay necesidad de tener un `Leer` ahí.

Comment: @instruye tienes varios problemas, y uno de ellos impide que podamos ver los otros y ayudarte mejor, que es lo de usar atributos `onmouseout=` en los enlaces `<a>` para lanzar la misma función que haciendo clic, pues molestan muchisimo y así es muy dificil ayudarte.  Quítalos de los enlaces si quieres nuestra ayuda de verdad y luego será más facil indicarte una buena solución.

Comment: MUCHA GRACIA masterguru  el 10 mar. a las 18:49 ya realice algunos cambios que me sugirieron le quite onmouseout

Comment: Tienes un problema de concepto. En la función Definida estas llamando a dos funciones más, las cuales no se esperan unas a otras, sino que van por su cuenta. Por lo tanto, cuando se intenta ejecutar el `myFunction()` la otra `bp0_id(6030)` aún no ha terminado ni ha mostrado el contenido correctamente, y por lo tanto la primera `myFunction()` no hace nada.  Intenta poner esa de `myFunction()` dentro del success de la `bp0_id(6030)`, al final de todo, cuando ya se haya procesado la salida, y teoricamente deberia funcionarte bien si solo tuvieras un `id="hore"`, pero ojo porque tienes dos.